# How to recover a broken Notification Center?

Tags: macos, notifications

After updating the computer, the Notification Center stopped working (widgets failed to load and there was a black box) so I tried this command to fix it, "defaults delete com.apple.notificationcenterui; killall NotificationCenter". But now the Notification Center doesn't even show the widgets. Picture here:

[image: Notification Center not working]

I've tried restarting the computer, entering safe mode but the problem still persists. Is there any solution to this?

*Notifications still appear but the widgets aren't to be seen anywhere*

Comment: There's a great workthrough on here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328386/notification-centre-what-happened-to-calculator-widget - it didn't actually fix me at that time, back in High Sierra days, but is worth a look.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the link. After trying out the methods, still doesn't seem to have been fixed though.

Comment: What version of macOS are you currently running?

Comment: @KevinGrabher macOS Ventura Beta. Forgot to mention it in the post!

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal This seems to be a somewhat common bug. I was facing the same, and it eventually resolved itself when I clicked "Clear All" when I had a few notifications. There are also a few threads about this issue on reddit.