# How to delete system file in Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, catalina, sip

Can't use sudo command in Terminal for destroy some unused system files. How can I do this? Who have a working answer for this?

Comment: May I ask why you want to delete a system file and which one? In most cases, this is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: [System Integrity Protection isn’t new to Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282496/). I’ll see if I can find a question that covers this already.

Comment: The entire read-only System volume is only 11 Gb. How much space do you plan to save? The files will get put back every update. There's absolutely no need, and you're likely to cause problems if the system does need those files.

Comment: My reason is very simple. I like an accurately in my folders. Some system apps I put to Utility folder, some to different folders. Bur after Catalina 10.15.3 update crash all my structure. I have 11 terrible picture without real programs and can't destroy them.

Answer (score 1):

I would boot to Recovery HD and use terminal (it is in the Utility menu) to remove the files you want to delete. SIP doesn’t need to be disabled on your system, just use a different system to do the delete and then restart back in the now modified system.

Keep in mind, deleting the file is easy to understand and execute. Making persistent changes (across updates or if Apple recreated the file you chose to delete) or effecting 
permission changes is significantly harder on Catalina due to the system / data split.

- [Catalina not allowing to change read/write permissions despite having SIP disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375603/catalina-not-allowing-to-change-read-write-permissions-despite-having-sip-disabl)

Answer (score -3):

1. Disable `csrutil` & restart
2. Hold <kbd>Opt</kbd>, boot from an **external bootable partition** in recovery mode. **Not active partition**(eg. High Sierra install on USB or another partition)
3. Run **Terminal**.
4. Locate your drive and delete or modify what you want. (Catalina and higher OS there will be 2 partitions.. but both will be able to modify, even read-only.
5. Re-enable `csrutil` immediately after.

Enjoy! Use to also delete `IOPlatformPluginfamily`. On Catalina and higher or lower.

Note: if you install updates, it will revert. Just redo steps.

Comment: Changing the content of the sealed partition in Big Sur and later will lead to unwanted side-effects.